# How to attach extra values after Input::all() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There's a comment form in page `http://localhost/posts/post_id`
When I submit the form, I want to attach the `post_id` value to `Input::all()` since the form doesn't include the input field for `post_id`. And the column name in comment table for post_id is called `post_id`,the route to create the comment is `comments.store`
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What does your route look like?  `Route::post('posts/{post_id}/comments', 'CommentsController@store')`?

Comment: It's a resource controller. `Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel change input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073633/laravel-change-input-value)

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work: `Input::merge(array('post_id' => $post_id));`

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```php
function store($post_id)
{
    $data = Input::all();

    $comment = new Comment($data);
    $comment->post_id = $post_id;
    $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion in the controller and passed the `post_id` value to view with `$post_id`.But I got an error with the form `{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('comments.store',$post_id))) }}` error: `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

`Request::instance()->query->set('key','value');`

Comment: Can you please add a bit of color around the code to make this a higher quality answer?

Comment: Can you do it for me please ?