# Laravel change input value

Tags: php, input, laravel-4

In laravel, we can get the input value via `Input::get('inputname')`. I try to change the value by doing this `Input::get('inputname') = "new value";`. But then, I get the error message saying `Can't use function return value in write context`.

Is it possible for us change the input value so that when later calling on `Input::get('inputname')` will get the new amended value?

Thanks.

Comment: You must assign it to a variable and then you can perform operations on the variable. The function `get` of the single pattern `Input` accepts a `string argument` and then perform's internal operations on the HTTP request to bring the data back to you, which is why you cannot treat it as a string. However, if you assign the value of that to a variable, then the variable can be manipulated thussly.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use `Input::merge()` to replace single items.

```
Input::merge(['inputname' => 'new value']);
```

Or use `Input::replace()` to replace the entire input array.

```
Input::replace(['inputname' => 'new value']);
```

Here's a [link to the documentation](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge)

Comment: _Note_: `Input::` is just a facade for `app('request')`. So `$request->merge, ->replace`... Work as well. Thx.

Comment: For `FormRequest` also might need to replace inner `$request->request` (instance of `ParameterBag`) with `$request->request->replace(array_merge($request->request->all(), $newData));`

Comment: Thanks for adding documentation

Comment: $request->replace instead of Input::replace removed all data from the input except the value I replaced.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking to do this in Laravel 5, you can use the `merge()` method from the `Request` class:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction( Request $request ) {

        // Split a bunch of email addresses
        // submitted from a textarea form input
        // into an array, and replace the input email
        // with this array, instead of the original string.
        if ( !empty( $request->input( 'emails' ) ) ) {

            $emails = $request->input( 'emails' );
            $emails = preg_replace( '/\s+/m', ',', $emails );
            $emails = explode( ',', $emails );

            // THIS IS KEY!
            // Replacing the old input string with
            // with an array of emails.
            $request->merge( array( 'emails' => $emails ) );
        }

        // Some default validation rules.
        $rules = array();

        // Create validator object.
        $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules );

        // Validation rules for each email in the array.
        $validator->each( 'emails', ['required', 'email', 'min: 6', 'max: 254'] );

        if ( $validator->fails() ) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } else {
            // Input validated successfully, proceed further.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you mean you want to overwrite input data, you can try doing:

```
Input::merge(array('somedata' => 'SomeNewData'));
```

Comment: Except it would be: `Input::merge(array('somedata'=> 'SomeNewData'));`

Answer (score 9):

Try this,it will help you.

```
$request->merge(array('someIndex' => "yourValueHere"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I also found this problem, I can solve it with the following code:

```
public function(Request $request)
{
    $request['inputname'] = 'newValue';
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel 8.
The following is working for me:
$request->attributes->set('name', 'Value');

Answer (score 0):

I used Raham's answer to solve my problem. However, it was nesting the updated data within an array, when I needed it at the same level as other data. I used:

```
$request->merge('someIndex' => "yourValueHere");
```

A note other Laravel newbies, I used the merge method to account for an empty checkbox value in a Laravel 7 update form. A deselected checkbox on an update form doesn't return 0, it doesn't set any value in the update request. As a result that value is unchanged in the database. You have to check for a set value and merge a new value if nothing exists.  Hope that helps someone.

Just a quick update. If the user doesn't check a box and I need to enter a value in the DB I do something like this in my controller:

```
    if(empty($request->input('checkbox_value'))) {
        $request->merge(['checkbox_value' => 0]);
    }
```