# Changing values of laravel inputs

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

First of all, i have read and tried what's on this post :
[Laravel change input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073633/laravel-change-input-value)

**My goal is to change some inputs' values on page load**, but i am doing wrong somewhere.

**i.e.** I have some inputs filled by user lately, now i want them to edit these fields. So i need to pull some data from database and insert these into my inputs.

**navTabs.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTab a').on(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    },myOnLoadFunction());
}

function myOnLoadFunction(){
   $.post('myRoute');
}
```

**Routes.php :**

```
Route::post('myRoute', array(
    'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod',
    'as' => 'myRoute'
));
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function myMethod(){
   Input::merge(array('myInputName' => 'theValueFromDatabase'));
}
```

So, i am making a mistake somewhere, but i couldn't find it out.
Everything works fine on test until **myMethod** i can get responses.
Am I using merge method wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
**MyController.php**

```
public function myMethod(){
   Input::merge(array('myInputName' => 'theValueFromDatabase'));
   //i have nearly 15 inputs here, assigning each of them one by one.
   $allVariablesWithNewInput = \Input::all();
   return Response::json($allVariablesWithNewInput);
}
```

Now this value is being returned to **navTabs.js**

```
function myOnLoadFunction(){
   $.post('myRoute', function(data){
      document.getElementById('myFieldID').value = data['myInputName'];
      //and assign 15 more inputs here to see values on html elements.
   });
}
```

First of all, thank you for your patience. **We figured out to find a solution to my problem with this way**. But i am not satisfied with this solution. I'm going to have to write a lot of code here. Is there any way to reduce repetition ? Do you offer an algorithm or something else ?

Thank you.

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth do you mean returning Input::get('inputname') ? I'll try this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `\Input::merge()` have you tried calling `\Input::get()` doesn't it give you the merged array?

Because `\Input::merge()` only adds the new set of input parameters that you pass and not return anything.

Let me know if this works:

```
public function myMethod(){
   Input::merge(array('myInputName' => 'theValueFromDatabase'));
   $newInputVariables = \Input::get('myInputName');
   $allVariablesWithNewInput = \Input::all();
}
```

Comment: this one works. Also returning values with return Response::json(Input::all()); I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

I see some errors which you should fix and maybe it will help.

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTab a').on('this needs an event', function (e) {  // 'click' maybe?
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    },myOnLoadFunction);  // Shouldn't put paranethesis
}

function myOnLoadFunction(){
      $.post('myRoute');
}
```

You likely aren't getting a response however because you aren't actually returning anything from your method.  If you are wanting to get json, try `return Response::json(Input::all());`

Comment: still working on it. by the way .on('load', function e) works. but myOnLoadFunction without () does not work.