# How to change value of a request parameter in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to change value of my request parameter like this:

```php
$request->name = "My Value!";
```

I use this code but does not work:

```php
$request->offsetSet('img', $img);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel change input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073633/laravel-change-input-value) - the answer is in the comment to the top question.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use `merge()`:

```
$request->merge([
    'user_id' => $modified_user_id_here,
]);
```

Simple! No need to transfer the entire `$request->all()` to another variable.

Read more about Laravel's `merge()` here:

https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-merge

Answer (score 263):

Try to:

```
$requestData = $request->all();
$requestData['img'] = $img;
```

Another way to do it:

```
$request->merge(['img' => $img]);
```

Thanks to @JoelHinz for this.

If you want to add or overwrite nested data:

```
$data['some']['thing'] = 'value';
$request->merge($data);
```

If you do not inject `Request $request` object, you can use the global `request()` helper or `\Request::` facade instead of `$request`

Comment: Error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::put()

Comment: put() is a collection method, $request->all() returns an array.

Comment: The request object actually has replace() and merge() methods. I generally prefer using those. See my comment on the question for a SO answer about that.

Comment: @JoelHinz, I thought they do not work in Laravel 5, because I saw few posts where guys had troubles with using these methods. But I've looked into the `Request` source code of L5 and I can see these methods. Thanks.

Comment: No sweat. Your answer is still wrong, though. The replace() method replaces the entire input - you need to merge() if you only want to replace one value.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. the `request()` helper saved me a ton of hassle!

Answer (score 11):

If you need to customize the request

```
$data = $request->all();
```

you can pass the name of the field and the value

```
$data['product_ref_code'] = 1650;
```

and finally pass the new request

```
$last = Product::create($data);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to update a property in the request, I recommend you to use the replace method from Request class used by Laravel

```
$request->replace(['property to update' => $newValue]);
```

Comment: Be careful, replace method remove original reqest data, and replace all it by your array.
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag line 54

    public function replace(array $parameters = [])
    {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

Comment: I'd avoid using replace(), it can result in some really annoying bugs with your API.

Comment: What about updating inside an array of a request?

Answer (score 10):

Use add

```
$request->request->add(['img' => $img]);
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: this is very useful when using $request object in a middleware. For example I'm using jwt for my api endpoint and my requests contains only jwt string. When user authenticated, I'm adding userId to $request object in middleware.

Comment: @Luís Fernando Thanks for you answer. It works for me that I actually needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you use custom requests for validation, for replace data for validation, or to set default data (for checkboxes or other) use override method `prepareForValidation()`.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin\Category;
    
class CategoryRequest extends AbstractRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        if ( ! $this->get('url')) {
            $this->merge([
                'url' => $this->get('name'),
            ]);
        }
        $this->merge([
            'url'    => \Str::slug($this->get('url')),
            'active' => (int)$this->get('active'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I hope this information will be useful to somebody.

Comment: In Laravel 9.x - not sure when the earliest, - you can use `mergeIfMissing`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#merging-additional-input. So your first example could be `$this->mergeIfMissing(['url' => $this->get('name')]);`

Answer (score 2):

It work for me

```
$request = new Request();
$request->headers->set('content-type', 'application/json');     
$request->initialize(['yourParam' => 2]);
```

check output

```
$queryParams = $request->query();
dd($queryParams['yourParam']); // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Great answers here but I needed to replace a value in a JSON request. After a little digging into the code, I came up with the following code. Let me know if I'm doing something dumb.

```
$json = $request->json()->all();
$json['field'] = 'new value';
$request->json()->replace($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
$request["name"] = "My New Value";
$request["img"]  = $img;
```

It's worked in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure to update the model class.

```
Item 
{
    fillable=[
        'img',
        ... // other attributes
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case of updating an item of object you can write the lines bellow

```
$Obj = $request->data;
$Obj['item'] = value;
```