# laravel : How to Store file uploaded path in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, storage

Here is my controller code :

```
 public function save(Request $request) {
    try {

        $this->validate($request, Country::rules());


        If(Input::hasFile('flag_image')){
            $file = Input::file('flag_image');
            $destinationPath = public_path(). '/images/admin/country/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image = time().$filename;
            $file->move($destinationPath, $image);
            $imgpath = 'public/images/admin/country/'.$image;
        }
        $request['flag_image'] = $imgpath;
        $country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($country !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('lists-country')->with('success', trans('Country data added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
    }
}
```

When I `dd($request)` before `saveOrUpdate` function I got the full path of the image uploaded file.

```
 +request: ParameterBag {#40 ▼
#parameters: array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "c94UG3R2PbbdHsXRLzs9OjEBTna23OHINFpki63U"
  "id" => ""
  "title" => "INDIA"
  "short_name" => "IN"
  "status" => "Active"
  "flag_image" => "public/images/admin/country/1515577652banner5.jpg"
]}
```

After successfully adding data on table a flag_image path look like `"D:\xampp\tmp\php63D3.tmp"` i want to store `"public/images/admin/country/1515577652banner5.jpg"` this path.

Comment: Try: `$country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request->all());` instead of `$country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request);` Hope this will fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`merge()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812476/how-to-change-value-of-a-request-parameter-in-laravel) it:

```
$request->merge(['flag_image' => $imgpath]);
```

Instead of:

```
$request['flag_image'] = $imgpath;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this one . Merge looks much cleaner , i didn't know about this one ,

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
$country->flag_image = $imgpath;
$country->save();
```

after

```
$country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request);
```

Comment: working thanx...but didnt understand what ll happen.?

Comment: @Javed with this code you'll update the table twice. Your `saveOrUpdate()` method will update the data and then `save()` will create another query to update `flag_image`

Comment: because you are registering everything in the request and the request has flag_image so if you want to prevent that just add $request->except('flag_image') to avoid that

Comment: as @Alexey Mezenin mention this will update twice if you want to avoid that just merge the array of the request with flag_image path like this Country::saveOrUpdate(array_merge($request->except('flag_image'), 'flag_image' , $imgpath) );

Comment: @Javed you should choose the best answer. If you'll use BM2ilabs' code tick his answer. If you'll use my code, tick my answer.

Comment: Also, if you'll use BM2ilabs' answer, you need to rewrite `saveOrUpdate()` because you're using `$request` object in it and `except()` will give you an array.