# Laravel overwrite value in request

Tags: laravel

I trouble to overwrite existing `request` value.

Below example `info` is my input array and `product` is my input array key.

e.g,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="info[product]" value="10" />
```

**PHP**

```
echo request('info.product');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10
```

**Edit**

```
print_r(request()->all());
Array
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [product] => 10
        )
    [_method] => PUT
    [info.product] => 20
)
```

Question : But now I am required to overwrite this default `10` value to `20` using laravel.

Comment: I've tested my solution and it works. If it doesn't work for you for some reason, please show results of `dd(request()->all())`

Comment: But we don't have `$request` parameter. We used `request()` instead of.

Comment: If you don't inject `Request $request` object, just use `request()` global helper or `\Request::` facade instead.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I used `request()->merge(['info.product' => 20]);` but nothing happen.

Comment: Please show where exactly do you use it and results of `dd(request()->all())`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin please check my **edit** after i try your answer.

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Laravel Framework version 5.2.45.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163230/discussion-between-jaydeep-mor-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin can you here ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Both solutions will work in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`merge()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812518/1227923) method:

```
$array['input']['product'] = 20;
request()->merge($array);
```

Or do this when you'll need the data from request:

```
$data = request()->all();
$data['input']['product'] = 20;
```

Comment: This logic remove another element from `info` array.

Comment: @JaydeepMor are you talking about the first solution or about the second one?

Comment: About second one.

Comment: @JaydeepMor just tried `$data = request()->all(); $data['input']['something'] = 40;` and `dd($data)` shows both `product` and `something`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
Input::merge(['input.product' => 'new value']);
```

and don't forget to import Input facade at the top.( `use Input;`)