# Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$values has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to alter an collection. but the error is already on the foorlooad even without content the error apears

```
foreach ($request->values as $id => &$value) {
        $values[1] = $this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][1];
        $values[2] = $this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][2];
        $values[3] = $this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][3];
        $values[4] = $this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][4];
        //dd($value);
    }
```

Comment: Adding data to request object is not a good idea. But if you really want to do this, here's [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812518/1227923). Your approach will not work.

Comment: You have `&$value` but are modifying `$values`, what are you trying to achieve by doing this? Why modify the request? Why not create a new collection with the repository items you need?

Comment: @apokryfos that is an typo because I was trying somthing else, but it does not even go there, it errors on the foreach

Comment: That's probably because `$request->values` does not exist. It is actually acquired via the magic `__get` method of the request so you can't pass elements of the result of that by reference because the result itself is not the actual underlying value. Again, why not create a new collection and work on that? Why do you need to modify the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactord my code to do the dame but with an new array instead of filling the existing $request

```
foreach ($request->values as $id => $value) {
        $values[$id][0] = $request->values[$id][0];
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                if (isset($this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][$i])) {
                    $values[$id][$i] = $this->repository->getById($request->id)->values[$id][$i];
                } else {
                    $values[$id][$i] = '';
                }
            }
        }
```