# How to add item to an array inside a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel Request object (collection) and there is an array inside this (address array)
I want to add a item to this array.
I tried `$request->address['state'] = 'test';` and following error occurred.

> Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$address has no effect

[image: Here is the request collection]

I want to add a item like highlighted in this img

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812476/how-to-change-value-of-a-request-parameter-in-laravel

Comment: @vijaykumar yes, but the above question solutions use to change collection values, but I want to add item to an array inside a collection

Comment: Have you even read the documentation? This is super trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way it to get the associative array from the request and play with it.

```
$myRequest = $request->all();
$myRequest['address'] = ['state' => 'test'];
```

otherwise, you have to modify the request object you need to add this code:

```
$request->merge([
    'address' => $myRequest
]);
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge