# How do I show a dynamic navigation bar on a dynamic web page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dynamic navigation bar, created however it won't show on the dynamic web page.

The current output is:
ErrorException
Undefined variable: navContent (View: C:\Users\Computer
Angel\Documents\blog\resources\views\page\dynamic.blade.php)

The desired output is my dynamic.blade.php where the pageContent is the dynamic page content the user inputted through a form and the dynamic navigation bar in the  tags.

This is my dynamic.blade.php:

```
<nav>
    @foreach($navContent as $nav)
    <a href="{!!$nav->navLink!!}">{!!nav-navName!!}</a>
    @endforeach        
    </nav>
    <body>
        {!!$pageContent->pageContent!!}
    </body>
```

This is my NavController.php:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Nav;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection;
class NavController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $navs = Nav::all();
        return view('navManagement', compact('navs'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('createNav');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'navName'            =>  'required',
            'navLink'              =>  'required',
       ]);
        $nav = new Nav([
            'navName'            =>    $request->get('navName'),
            'navLink'              =>    $request->get('navLink'),
        ]);
        $nav->save();
        return redirect('/n');
    }
    public function show($navName)
    {
        $navContent = DB::table('navs')->where('navName',$navName)->first();
        return view('page.dynamic', ['navContent' => $navContent]);
    }
    public function edit($navName)
    {
        $navContent = DB::table('navs')->where('navName',$navName)->first();
        return view('editNav', ['navContent' => $navContent]);
    }
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'navName' => 'required|exists:navs,navName',
            'navLink' => 'required'
        ]);
        $obj = \App\Nav::where('navName', $request->navName)
            ->update([
                'navLink' => $request->navLink
           ]);
        return redirect('/n');
    }
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $obj = \App\Nav::where('navName', $request->navName)
        ->delete();
        return redirect('/n');
    }
}
```

This is my PageController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection;
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $pages = Page::all();
        return view('pageManagement', compact('pages'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        //This will load create.blade.php
        return view('createPage');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title'            =>  'required',
            'URI'              =>  'required|min:5|max:10|',
            'pageContent'      =>  'required',
        ]);
        $page = new Page([
            'title'            =>    $request->get('title'),
            'URI'              =>    $request->get('URI'),
            'pageContent'      =>    $request->get('pageContent'),
        ]);
        $page->save();
        return redirect('/p');
    }
    public function show($URI)
    {
        $pageContent = DB::table('pages')->where('URI',$URI)->first();
        return view('page.dynamic', ['pageContent' => $pageContent]);
    }
    public function edit($URI)
    {
        $pageContent = DB::table('pages')->where('URI',$URI)->first();
        return view('editPage', ['pageContent' => $pageContent]);
    }
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'URI' => 'required|min:5|max:10|exists:pages,URI',
            'pageContent' => 'required'
        ]);
        $obj = \App\Page::where('URI', $request->URI)
            ->update([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'pageContent' => $request->pageContent
           ]);
        return redirect('/p');
    }
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $obj = \App\Page::where('URI', $request->URI)
        ->delete();
        return redirect('/p');
    }
}
```

This is my Nav.php:

```
class Nav extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['navName', 'navLink'];
}
```

This is my Page.php:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'URI', 'pageContent'];
}
```

This is my migration for pages:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('URI');
            $table->text('pageContent');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my migration for nav:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('navs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('navName');
            $table->string('navLink');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my createNav.blade.php:

```
<form action="/storeNav" method="post">
@csrf
  <label for="navName">Navigation Bar Option Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="navName" name="navName" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('navName') }}"> 
<br>
  @error('navName') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="navLink">Navigation Bar Option Link:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="navLink" name="navLink" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('navLink') }}"> 
<br>
  @error('navLink') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my createPage.blade.php:

```
<form action="/storePage" method="post">
@csrf
  <label for="title">Title:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('title') }}"><br>
  @error('title') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="URI">URI:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="URI" name="URI" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('URI') }}"><br>
  @error('URI') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <label for="pageContent">Page Content:</label><br>
  <textarea id="pageContent" name="pageContent" value="{{ old('pageContent') }}"></textarea>
  @error('pageContent') <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/page/{URI}', 'PageController@show');
Route::get('/page/{URI}/edit', 'PageController@edit');
Route::get('/p', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('/createPage', 'PageController@create');
Route::post('/storePage', 'PageController@store');
Route::patch('/page/{URI}', 'PageController@update');
Route::delete('/page/{URI}', 'PageController@destroy');
Route::get('/nav/{navName}/edit', 'NavController@edit');
Route::get('/n', 'NavController@index');
Route::get('/createNav', 'NavController@create');
Route::post('/storeNav', 'NavController@store');
Route::patch('/nav/{navName}', 'NavController@update');
Route::delete('/nav/{navName}', 'NavController@destroy');
```

Below is my github repository link, if you want to take a look at my full code, or you want to try run the code in your Integrated Development Environment.
https://github.com/xiaoheixi/blog

Thanks for reading! :D

Answer (score 0):

If is complaining that it can't find a variable called `$navContent`.

I can't see you passing it to either of the views you are calling from your `index()` functions.

```
return view('navManagement', compact('navs'));
return view('pageManagement', compact('pages'));
```

You would need to set that varaible and pass it to the view

```
// Get the nav content however you want, this is just a crude example
$navContent = $this->getMyNavContent();

return view('navManagement', [
    'navs'       => $navs,
    'navContent' => $navContent
]);
```

Comment: That isn't the method for this question. basically navManagement loads up navManagement.blade.php and pageManagement loads up pageManagement.blade.php. What I am asking is, how to show both navContent and pageContent from two different controllers to the dynamic.blade.php.

Comment: Mainly talking about the show function on both controllers, in the PageController the show function, shows the dynamic page content. On the NavController the show function shows the dynamic navigation bar. But when I want both the navigation bar and page content to show, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to find a way to embed the dynamic nav without having to add the `navContent` every time you render a view, as that's what the other answer is suggesting. You could achieve this using a middleware, say `dynamicNav` and registering your routes under that middleware group.

In that middleware you can do all the logic of fetching the nav content and then use something like `merge`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812476/how-to-change-value-of-a-request-parameter-in-laravel):
`$request->merge(['dynamicNav' => $navContent]);`

This way your middleware will add the data to every request which goes through it, although I wouldn't recommend this solution.

What I would do is cache the nav content and retrieve in the view using the `cache()` helper, then override the `save()` method of the model to also update the cache when the DB is updated (to avoid duplicate code, you could create a trait for the fetching of the nav). Example:

```php
// in your model

public function save(array $options = [])
{
    Cache::put('nav-content', getNavContent());
    parent::save();
}
```

Comment: I already fixed it, its actually super easy to fix. Let me share you my solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883304/how-do-i-use-components-to-display-my-dynamic-navigation-bar-using-laravel

Comment: That question is another one of my questions, it shows my solution and it works for me. Very ingenious idea of doing it though, by just getting the variable in the boot method.