# Replace content of request laravel

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-8, laravel-request

I want to replace the content inside a request of Laravel. How can I do that? To replace the content and save inside the same request?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try searching before posting a new question.  I searched for "*laravel replace data in request*" and found man answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change value of a request parameter in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812476/how-to-change-value-of-a-request-parameter-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` method.

**Example**

```
$request->request->replace($newData);
```