# Request only method returns original request array

Tags: laravel

So I'm manipulating Request and setting an object to new value.

```
$assignable = ['seats'];
$request->seats = $this->myMethod($request->seats);

var_dump($request->seats); //works
$data = $request->only($assignable);
var_dump($data['seats']); // returns the initial value of 'seats' (without passing through $this->myMethod)
```

Now I know I could first convert the request object to array and then manipulate the '$data', but the above code is a sample and the real code is much more complicated, it would require to change the whole architecture to do that way.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: This question is about `Input()` but it is the same for request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073633/laravel-change-input-value.  The comment under the question explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$request->seats = $this->myMethod($request->seats);
```

Try this:

```
$request->merge(['seats' => $this->myMethod($request->seats)]);
```